# C# regex match always return false

Tags: c#, regex, match

Here are my test case for c# regex match:

```
AAA
BB
AAA+15d
BB-205w
```

The pattern i have used is: `@"^(AAA|BB)([\+|\-]\d+[d|w])*$"`, when i test it online in some .net regex tester, it says match. but when i run it in c# codes, always return false for the last two test cases. What is wrong with the pattern?

Comment: Show your C# code. BTW you don't need `|` ( alteration) within character class. `[+-]` and `[dw]` will be just fine.

Comment: The regex really works, but can be a bit enhanced to [`^(AAA|BB)([+-]\d+[dw])*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(AAA%7cBB)(%5b%2b-%5d%5cd%2b%5bdw%5d)*%5cr%3f%24&i=AAA%0d%0aBB%0d%0aAAA%2b15d%0d%0aBB-205w&o=m)

Comment: var pattern = @"^(AAA|BB)([+-]\d+[DW])*$";
           
 bool isMatch =Regex.IsMatch(pattern, "AAA+180D", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: *item, pattern order reversed* - so the question should be closed as not reproducible due to a typo.

Comment: Check out https://dotnetfiddle.net/ for demonstrating working examples. This can be beneficial in getting a response and representing a clearer view of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't reproduce the mentioned behaviour

```
List<string> Input = new List<string>() { "AAA", "BB", "AAA+15d", "BB-205w" };
string Pattern = @"^(AAA|BB)([+-]\d+[dw])*$";
foreach (string item in Input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(item, Pattern));
}
```

Result:

```
True 
True 
True 
True
```

Comment: This might be necessary for *demo* only. The strings are most probably tested independently. Without the modifier flag, OP can match the first 2  strings.

Comment: @fubo thank you both very much, i saw what's wrong with the c# code. i have the item, pattern order reversed.